# Get current post ID in javascript - WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am making a plugin for wordpress. The plugin will add a tinymce on the edit post, and it will send the post_id to the database to do some identification later.

In my case, I am writing a javascript, which directory in `wordpress\wp-content\plugins\facebook-api\js\shortcode-tinymce-button.js`. And now I have no idea how I can get the post_Id in javascript.

Here is what I am doing:

1. user click the `OK button` will send the post_Id and the text box value to the database.
   [image]

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add('facebook_api_tinymce', function( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'facebook_api_tinymce', 
            {
        title: 'Set friend condition', 
                    text: 'Condition',
                    type: 'menubutton',
                     menu: 
                     [    
                         {
                             text: 'Friend',
                              onclick: function() {
                                 editor.windowManager.open( {
                                     body:[
                                          {
                                            type: 'textbox',
                                            name: 'textboxName',
                                            label: 'Set friend',
                                            value: '20'     
                                          }
                                        ],onsubmit: function( e ) {

                                            var $hi = "php echo get_the_ID();";
                                            alert($hi);
                                            $no_friend_e = parseInt(e.data.textboxName);
                                           //Pass the value the PHP file, which is doing the database update.
                                           jQuery.ajax({
                                                url: 'http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/facebook-api/js/databaseConnection.php',
                                                type: 'POST',
                                                data: {functionname: 'updateDatabase', post_id: '1', no_friend: $no_friend_e},
                                                error:function(data){  //When Can't call the PHP function
                                                   alert("failed");
                                                    console.log(data);
                                                },
                                                success: function(data) {  //update data successful
                                                    alert("success");
                                                    console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }

                                });    

                                 function get_post_content(id){ //Didn't use
                                            return document.getElementById("post-"+id).innerHTML;
                                 }//you should probably use textContent/innerText but I am not going to get into that here

                              }

                          }
                     ]

    });

});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look into this -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly do you need? You cannot use `"php echo get_the_ID();"` in your javascript. That just won't do. You can localize the post id in an object that will be available for you to pick up. You can check out the tutorial I made about TinyMCE editor, and adding new buttons to it, maybe you'll get some ideas there: http://madebydenis.com/adding-shortcode-button-to-tinymce-editor/